How to count if your column has the same values on another column in separate related table
I wanted to count the values that has the same position on my table and with my previous related table.
What I did was
=Calculate(Countrows(Table1,Filter(Table1,Table1[Position] = Table2[Position])

1ST Table
**ID    Position**
3383669 Manager
3482615 Associate
3372059 Sr Associate
3362498 Associate
2150465 Associate

2ND Table
**ID    Position**
3383669 Director
3482615 Sr Associate
3372059 Manager
3362498 Associate
2150465 Associate

I'm expecting that the answer would be 2 as two ID has the same positions from previous to recent.
What I did was
=Calculate(Countrows(Table1,Filter(Table1,Table1[Position] = Table2[Position])

I expect that 2 as two ID has the same positions from previous to recent.
It only showed

Error This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without


you can't do it in that way, you need to bring both population to separate variable tables  and then do INTERSECT and create third table and then you can count rows

you can try this
measure =
VAR tbl =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        Table1,
        "check",
            IF (
                MAXX (
                    FILTER (
                        Table2,
                        Table1[ID] = Table2[ID]
                            && Table1[Position] = Table2[Position]
                    ),
                    Table2[Position]
                ) = Table1[Position],
                1,
                0
            )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( tbl, [check] )



This works!  can you explain how did it work starting from the var tbl to sumx?

var is to create a temp table and add a new column, if matches, display 1. At last sum the new column
